# Include C# files code at aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to execute the following code at my `C#` page. I know that there are more questions like this here, but I could not find something that could help me. However I get an server error at the very first line

```
The server block is not well formed
```

The code is:

```
<%@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; %>
<%@using System; %>
<%@using Project.Models;%>
<%@using Project.Controllers;%>

WebIntegrationRestService<int,int> service= new WebIntegrationRestService<int,int>();
service.GetUserByUsername(0,1,User.Identity.Name);
UserType type = null;
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    UserType type = service.GetUserByUsername(0, 1, User.Identity.Name).First().UserType;
}

if (type==UserType.TypeA)
{
    %> <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Add User ", "Create", "User")%></li> <%
}
```

Comment: Why are you using 'import' and 'using' in one file ? Import is VB.NET - using is the C# equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I copied them wrong. It is using that I wanted, and I am fixing that now at my question. However, this is not the problem..

Comment: `@import` is a page directive that does what `using` does in code files & works regardless of the page language. `@using` is made-up nonsense that won't work.

Comment: Also you shouldn't really post the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

You have unbalanced code tags.

```
<%@ import Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; %>
<%@ import System; %>
<%@using Project.Models;%>
<%@using Project.Controllers;%>

<%

    WebIntegrationRestService<int,int> service= new WebIntegrationRestService<int,int>();
    service.GetUserByUsername(0,1,User.Identity.Name);
    UserType type = null;
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        UserType type = service.GetUserByUsername(0, 1, User.Identity.Name).First().UserType;
    }


    if (type==UserType.TypeA){%>

    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Add User ", "Create", "User")%></li>        

    <% } %>
```

Notice I added an opening code tag between your page-level declarations and the start of your code.

I also added one after the last closing brace.

You should re-think what you're doing though. When you start putting this sort of thing in your views you are asking for trouble (maintenence costs of keeping things in Views, debugging issues, duplicate code, etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this did not help me. I get exactly the same error, at the exact same line. Basically, what I am trying to do is to check the type of the user who is logged in, to display different menus for each different type of user. do you know a more clear way to do that?